# How can I extract text from google chrome application using pywinauto?

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I'm trying extract list texts on column "Assunto" from windows POP-UP in google chrome using pywinauto.

[POP-UP image on google chrome here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q6xv.png)

```
    app = Application().connect(title_re='AgênciaNet', timeout=10)
    time.sleep(1)
    window = app.Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND
    window.set_focus()
    window.maximize()
    window.print_control_identifiers()
```

Control Identifiers:

```
Chrome_WidgetWin_1 - 'AgênciaNet - Secretaria de Economia do Distrito Federal - Google Chrome'    (L-8, T-8, R1032,
B736)
['AgênciaNet - Secretaria de Economia do Distrito Federal - Google ChromeChrome_WidgetWin_1', 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1',
'AgênciaNet - Secretaria de Economia do Distrito Federal - Google Chrome']
child_window(title="AgênciaNet - Secretaria de Economia do Distrito Federal - Google Chrome", class_name="Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
   |
   | Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND - 'Chrome Legacy Window'    (L0, T71, R1024, B728)
   | ['Chrome Legacy Window', 'Chrome Legacy WindowChrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND', 'Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND', 'Chrome Legacy Window0', 'Chrome Legacy Window1', 'Chrome Legacy WindowChrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND0', 'Chrome Legacy WindowChrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1', 'Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND0', 'Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1']
   | child_window(title="Chrome Legacy Window", class_name="Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND")
   |
   | Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND - 'Chrome Legacy Window'    (L0, T0, R1024, B657)
   | ['Chrome Legacy Window2', 'Chrome Legacy WindowChrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND2', 'Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND2']
   | child_window(title="Chrome Legacy Window", class_name="Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND")
   |
   | Intermediate D3D Window - ''    (L0, T0, R1024, B728)
   | ['AgênciaNet - Secretaria de Economia do Distrito Federal - Google ChromeIntermediate D3D Window', 'Intermediate D3D Window']
   | child_window(class_name="Intermediate D3D Window")
```

[My inspecter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlwFm.png)

I need get tag "Name". Anyone can help me please. Ty!

Specifications:

- Pywinauto 0.6.8
- Python 3.10.7
- Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First please make sure your target window has the same `ProcessId` in `Inspect.exe`. If the process is different than for Chrome window, you need to connect or use something like:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

window = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Selecione um certificado")
window.child_window(title_re="MERCADAO COMERCIO.*", control_type="DataItem").click_input()
window.child_window(title="OK", control_type="Button").invoke()
```

For better understanding how it works I would recommend reading the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

If this is a self-drawn "window" on the page, there is trick for Chrome:
https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/How-to-enable-accessibility-(tips-and-tricks)

Or use this example:
https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/ui-automation-course/blob/master/02_google_drive_Murashov/test_explorer_google_drive.py

Comment: Thank you Vasily Ryabov, you helped me so much!!! :D

Comment: I started browser with webdriver selenium in python and using pywinauto to automate one step, but it's doesn't worked to me. Can I do it Vasily?

Comment: If Chrome is started with desktop accessibility option, pywinauto can do all what you need. If the error is not clear, please post one more question with tag `pywinauto` with all the details: code snippet, traceback etc.